# Responsive smoothmenu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress which is not responsive.

I am using smoothmenu on that website.

Is there is any way to make menu responsive.

```
ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})
```

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Making it responsive depends on a lot of factors... I don't know what's smoothmenu, but we would need to see if the markup is made to make the site responsive, like the viewport metatag, etc

Comment: i have added viewport for the same. already..

Comment: What is smooth menu? is that a plugin? Can you provide an URL?

Comment: its simple jquery plugin